# Python: xarray and h5py incompatibility

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf, python-xarray, h5py

The code below sends an error "**RuntimeError: NetCDF: HDF error**". If I remove the import h5py, I get no error. Are there any suggestions on why this might be happening and how I can fix it? My ultimate aim is to load a hdf5 and write out to netCDF.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import h5py 
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.Dataset(
     {"foo": (("x", "y"), np.random.rand(4, 5))},
     coords={
         "x": [10, 20, 30, 40],
         "y": pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=5),
         "z": ("x", list("abcd")),
     },
  )  
 ds.to_netcdf("saved_on_disk.nc")
```

Comment: What happens if you reverse the `h5py` and `xarray` imports?

Comment: Thanks Bart, this helped me find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import xarray as xr
```

Works.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import h5py 
import xarray as xr
```

Doesn't Work

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import xarray as xr
import h5py
```

Doesn't Work

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import xarray as xr
import h5py
```

Works!

The key was also loading the netCDF4 package.